# Plus 1 button doesn't render properly in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, google-plus, google-plus-one

I noticed recently the Plus 1 button on my company's website doesn't render properly in IE 9 and 10. Looks perfect in Chrome, but can't seem to get it to show up in IE without a chunk being cut off the bottom of the button. Compatability Mode doesn't help. Any tricks to position or pad around the button so it shows up properly? I tried putting the code in table but that didn't help at all, nor does paragraph or break.

Facebook Like button shows up correctly in both IE and Chrome.

Windows Server 2008, IIS 7.5, using the code generated on the developer site.

Thanks

Comment: You're going to need to supply some code. It would be best to strip down the code to the very minimum you can post here or on jsfiddle that demonstrates the issue. I mean absolute bare minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add the following code and the browser will force to IE8 mode (which renders correctly):

Add this to the top of your HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Add this to the head section of your HTML

```
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

The button will then render correctly. See [a live example here](http://wheresgus.com/appactivitiesdemo/).

Comment: That works, thanks. Reveals a lot of other issues with the code on the site, but otherwise resolves the button issue.

Comment: I am already using "<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">" there will be any issue if I use both meta.